# Counting multiplications (complexity function)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I'm trying to count the number of times multiplication appears in an expression (for the purpose of constructing a ComplexityFunction that would help me simplify a terrible algebraic expression for later numerical crunching in matlab).

For example, I consider the following expression to involve 3 multiplications:

```
a b c + d e
```

two in "abc" and one in "de".

I've tried Level, but unfortunately mathematica sees the term "abc" as one "Times" with three arguments:

```
 In:= Level[a b c + d e, {-1}, Heads->True]
Out:= {Plus, Times, a, b, c, Times, c, d}
```

In principle I could reverse-engineer the multiplicity of arguments of "Times" from the above, but that seems like an unnecessarily cumbersome way.

i'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: "but that seems like an unnecessarily cumbersome way." — unless I'm mistaken, that seems to be the only sensible option, since with the `Flat` attribute of `Times`, you'll never see `Times[a, Times[b, c]]`. There might be dark, back alley routes to spelunk and do some ugly pre-parsing, etc., but I don't think it'd be any less "cumbersome", not to mention the loss in intent and clarity. As an alternative, you could consider converting your expression to `InputForm`, then a string and counting the `*`s

Comment: thanks for the input. indeed, counting `*` in the `InputForm` string is most in line with what i originally hoped to accomplish, thanks!

Comment: I wonder if *Mathematica* might be able to simplify the terrible algebraic expression for you -- but that's a different question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way to count the number of multiplications in an expression (equal to or greater than the number of `Times` in the expression).  It should also work for several other binary operators, `Listable` or not (although I haven't tested it on them).

```
t[x_, oper_: Times] := Tr @ ((Length[#] - 1) & /@
                       (Extract[x, {Sequence @@ Drop[#, -1]}] & /@ Position[x, oper]))
```

**Usage**

```
t[a b c + d e + f[a b] - 1/f[f[c d]]]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

---

**Under the hood**.

Let's examine `a b c + d e + f[a b] - 1/f[f[c d]]`, using `Position` and `Extract` and `TreeForm`.

The tree structure of the expression...

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, e, f]
(x = a b c + d e + f[a b] - 1/f[f[c d]]) // TreeForm
```

[image: times1]

Then the positions of the head, `Times`.

```
Position[x, Times]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0}}
> ```

By dropping the final zero from each position, we obtain the instances of `Times`, including the arguments.

```
Extract[x, {Sequence @@ Drop[#, -1]}] & /@ %
```

> ```
> {a b c, d e, a b, -(1/f[f[c d]]), c d}
> ```

...the number of items.

```
Length[%]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

[`t[]` goes a step further to count the (arguments-1) for each `Times`, namely, 6.]

...a look at the structure of each of those instances of `Times`.

```
TreeForm /@ %%
```

[image: times2]

Comment: N.B. this only works with `Listable` functions because you allow the whole expression to evaluate first. Properly speaking, one should hold it unevaluated and take the length of the arguments of `Listable` functions into account when adding up the number of operations.

Answer (score 11):

This is a rather simple-minded approach, but maybe it will be useful to you:

```
ClearAll[opCount];
opCount[h_, expr_] := Cases[
  Hold[expr],
  HoldPattern@h[args : _ ~Repeated~ {2, Infinity}] :> Length@Hold[args] - 1,
  -2
 ] // Total;
SetAttributes[opCount, HoldRest];
```

Let's try:

```
opCount[Times, 1*2*3*4*5 + 6*7*8]
(* -> 6 *)

opCount[Plus, 1*2*3*4*5 + 6*7*8]
(* -> 1 *)
```

So, it seems workable. But, please note that this is only correct for *n*-ary functions where the number of "individual" operations scales as *n* - 1 (e.g. `Plus`, `Times`, their inverses, `Dot`, etc.), and will not be correct in general for listable functions when lists appear in the arguments. That is, `{1, 2, 3}*{4, 5, 6}` will be seen as one multiplication, although in fact three are performed.

Answer (score 8):

One possible compact solution:

```
multCount[expr_] := Total[Length /@ List @@@ Cases[expr, _Times, \[Infinity]] - 1]

multCount[a b c + d e]
(* 3 *)

multCount[a*b*c + (d*e)/(f*g*h - i*j*k*l)]
(* 10 *)
```

Notice that since Mathematica represents divisions by multiplications with the multiplicative inverse and subtractions by additions with the number multiplied by (-1), the second expression gets a higher count than the expected 8 multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

(This is basically an comment to the answer from David Carraher but I am not allowed to comment on this one.)

The complexity function

```
t[x_, oper_: Times] := Tr @ ((Length[#] - 1) & /@
                       (Extract[x, {Sequence @@ Drop[#, -1]}] & /@ Position[x, oper]))
```

has one minor problem: If the first element is a "times" operator, it doesn't count correctly, e.g.

```
test = a*b*(d + e + h*x*(t + x))
```

`t[test]` then evaluates to 1 instead of 4.

I (think I) solved this problem by using

```
myt[x_, oper_: Times] := 
 Tr[Map[(Length[#] - 1) &, 
   Flatten[Extract[x, {Drop[#, -1]}] & /@ Position[x, oper]]]]
```

instead.