# Counting the number of operations performed during a calculation

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, numerics, core-language

I need to know how can I count the number of operations performed during a calculation of a `CompoundExpression`.

In some of these expressions there are `Dot` products between matrices and I want to count how many additions a multiplications are performed in each of these calculations.

In other words, I need a functions that does the same as the function `cost` of Maple (http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=codegen/cost)

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What kind of expressions did you have in mind? Polynomials and the like shouldn't be hard, but you're probably not going to be able to do it reliably for something way more complicated...

Comment: For instance, I want to know how many additions and multiplications Mathematica performs during the evaluation of an expression like `LinearSolve[Dot[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {3, 4}}], {5, 6}]`

Comment: I'm giving this a vote because I've never seen a question like it, but outside of some external low-level debugging tool I have no idea how one would snoop on that kind of thing.  Many numeric operations are passed to libraries such as the Intel MKL and are therefore outside *Mathematica's* direct control anyway.

Comment: @Nasser: it stopped just now..it was there about half an hour ago.It says undergoing maintenance.

Comment: [This example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TraceScan.html#701928725) in the docs claims to "count additions and multiplications of machine numbers needed for a numerical computation".

Comment: @Nasser ["The Maplesoft web site you are requesting is currently undergoing scheduled maintenance."](http://www.maplesoft.com/)

Comment: @MichaelE2 However, if you try to adapt it to the following case:
`Block[{c = 0},{TraceScan[c++&,LinearSolve[Dot[{{1.,2.},{3.,4.}},{{5.,6.},{3.,4.}}],{5.,6.}],(Plus|Times)[__?MachineNumberQ]],c}]`
the result for **c** is zero.

Comment: I'm not surprised.  Counting `Times` and `Plus` is not the same as counting the number of times the CPU executes one of its addition or multiplication operations (or whatever one means by "addition" and "multiplication").  I do recall a similar question recently, but I think it was closed and perhaps deleted.  What that person was after seemed impossible to some.  The example from the docs is the best I can offer you.  There are others might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: Anyway, this example from the docs may be useful for many people having the same doubt. Thank you, @MichaelE2

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT AT ALL answer to this question, but I am just writing my opinion here. Link shown for Maple, counts only number of atomic operations and doesn't inform anything about kernel level instructions which I believe is not more significant than Timing.I tried the following and it gives the same kind of output. All that is needed is to put it together in a function.
For example,

```
t = {et = Plus[a x^2 + (b/s)  x + c, x], Times[a, b]} // FullForm
```

than counting operations as,

```
Count[t, _Plus, Infinity] (*7)
Count[t, _Times, Infinity] (*9*)
Count[t, _Power, Infinity] (*5*)
Count[t, Power[a_, b_] /; b < 1, Infinity] (*1*)
```

In this way operations can be enlisted and total number of instructions can be fetched. I hope I have understood the question correctly and not missing on any subtlety.

Edit: In case of Numeric calculation use `HoldForm`, as under,

```
t = HoldForm[123 675 + 234/124 + 34/67 + 23^34] // FullForm
Count[t, _Power, Infinity](*3*)
Count[t, Power[a_, b_] /; b < 1, Infinity](*2*)
Count[t, _Times, Infinity](*3*)
```

Comment: Actually I have been trying to build some functions based on the answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25760/counting-multiplications-complexity-function), which is a generalization of the aproach you are proposing. However, I need something that works with numeric calculations. I am not sure whether or not it is possible. Anyway, thank you for the attention.
Also, thank you for clarifying how the `cost` function works at Maple.

Comment: actually thanks for link, it should have been listed in comments above,its pretty informative.