# How to reduce the number of operations needed to evaluate an expression?

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

For some numerical calculations in C++ I have, for example, this complicated expression to evaluate. Given as Mathematica input, in its original form it is

```
w - 4(w - y)((w - y)^2 y + 6(1 + y)((w - y)y + (1 + y)^2)) /
((w - y)^2 ((w - y)y + 6y^2 + 8y(1 + y)) + (1 + y)^2 (36(w - y)y + 24(1 + y)^2))
```

The goal is to reduce the number of required floating point operations to evaluate it in C++. Using useful code from [Counting multiplications (complexity function)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25760/counting-multiplications-complexity-function) we can see it requires the following operations and their respective counts: `{{Times, 22}, {Plus, 18}, {Power, 7}}`. The `FullSimplify`'ed expression is a bit shorter

```
w - 4(w - y)(6 + y(18 + 6w + w^2 + 4(3 + w)y + y^2)) /
(24 + y(w^3 + w^2 (8 + 11y) + (2 + y)(48 + y(30 + y)) + w(36 + y(56 + 11y))))
```

and requires the following operation counts: `{{Times, 16}, {Plus, 18}, {Power, 5}}`.

One way to reduce the number of operations is to identify common components and evaluate them beforehand as temporaries. After staring at the expression for an hour I could find the following substitutions:

```
f0 = w - y;
f1 = 1 + y;
f00 = f0 f0;
f11 = f1 f1;
f0y = f0 y;
```

and the expression now reads

```
w - 4f0(6f1(f11 + f0y) + f00 y) / (f11(24f11 + 36f0y) + f00(6y y + 8f1 y + f0y))
```

The operation count is now: `{{Times, 19}, {Plus, 9}, {Power, 0}}`.

Is there a way to express this process of finding sub-expressions more formally in Mathematica? And automatize it at least for such simple expressions involving only multiplication and addition?

Comment: Surely you know that aggressive reordering of expressions can change (often decrease) rounding accuracy of IEEE754 end result? If your goal is to reduce amount of operations in code generated by C compiler, you can use standards-noncompliant compiler option such as `--ffast-math` which probably knows very well how to reorder this kind of expressions. Otherwise - well, I'm intrigued to hear of a solution in Mathematica.

Comment: @kirma Yes, I know. But I don't believe compilers dare to do this kind of temporary substitution; IMHO the existing operations are just reordered in time in order to optimize usage of various FP units and reduce congestion of the pipelines. Nevertheless, you raise a valid point, but the way how this expression was obtained is by deriving it first on paper and then some additional work was done with Mathematica and `Simplify`. You can see that during all these stages, the expressions get reordered randomly, either by human standards of beauty or length.

Comment: @kirma This could be an interesting question, what is the form of this expression so that the rounding error is minimal?

Comment: Compilers such as gcc have `--ffast-math` specifically for this purpose. It's enabled only on "unsafe" optimization levels by default if ever. The funniest part about IEEE754 arithmetic is that even summation is an ordered operation; `a+b+c` is likely to produce different result from `a+c+b`. Compilers wear the consistency straightjacket by default, but if you use `--ffast-math`, are relieved (at least to some useful extent) of it. Of course, this is relatively irrelevant point if your question is considered purely on the context of Mathematica.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the expression optimizer that is used within compile:

```
in = w - 4 (w - 
     y) ((w - y)^2 y + 
      6 (1 + y) ((w - y) y + (1 + y)^2))/((w - y)^2 ((w - y) y + 
         6 y^2 + 8 y (1 + y)) + (1 + y)^2 (36 (w - y) y + 
         24 (1 + y)^2));

Experimental`OptimizeExpression[in]
(*
Experimental`OptimizedExpression[
 Block[{Compile`$1, Compile`$2, Compile`$5, Compile`$3, Compile`$6, 
       Compile`$7}, Compile`$1 = -y; Compile`$2 = w + Compile`$1; 
      Compile`$5 = 1 + y; Compile`$3 = Compile`$2^2; 
      Compile`$6 = Compile`$2 y; Compile`$7 = Compile`$5^2; 
      w - (4 Compile`$2 (Compile`$3 y + 
        6 Compile`$5 (Compile`$6 + 
               Compile`$7)))/(Compile`$3 (Compile`$6 + 6 y^2 + 
             8 y Compile`$5) + 
      Compile`$7 (36 Compile`$2 y + 24 Compile`$7))]]
*)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent. Remarkably, your output is really identical to the temporaries I found above. Thanks!

Comment: I guess this output could be with some pattern matching simply transformed into a nested `With[]` statement...

Answer (score 6):

Maybe we can learn something from what `Compile` produces.

```
cf = Compile[
  {{w, _Real}, {y, _Real}}
  ,
  w - 4 (w - 
      y) ((w - y)^2 y + 
       6 (1 + y) ((w - y) y + (1 + y)^2))/((w - y)^2 ((w - y) y + 
          6 y^2 + 8 y (1 + y)) + (1 + y)^2 (36 (w - y) y + 
          24 (1 + y)^2))
  ]
```

In the compiled code we see that at least the number of squares was reduced. The option "ExpressionOptimization" is responsible for this. The default setting is `Automatic`, which if there are no external calls to the kernel, is basically equivalent to `True`. The compiled code can be viewed as follows

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
cf // CompilePrint
```

giving

```
        2 arguments
        6 Integer registers
        12 Real registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        R1 = A2
        I0 = 1
        I2 = 6
        I3 = 8
        I5 = 24
        I1 = 4
        I4 = 36
        Result = R10


1   R2 = - R1
2   R3 = R0 + R2
3   R4 = I0
4   R4 = R4 + R1
5   R5 = Square[ R3]
6   R6 = R3 * R1
7   R7 = Square[ R4]
8   R8 = R5 * R1
9   R9 = R6 + R7
10  R10 = I2
11  R10 = R10 * R4 * R9
12  R8 = R8 + R10
13  R10 = Square[ R1]
14  R9 = I2
15  R9 = R9 * R10
16  R10 = I3
17  R10 = R10 * R1 * R4
18  R11 = R6 + R9 + R10
19  R9 = R5 * R11
20  R11 = I4
21  R11 = R11 * R3 * R1
22  R10 = I5
23  R10 = R10 * R7
24  R11 = R11 + R10
25  R10 = R7 * R11
26  R9 = R9 + R10
27  R10 = Reciprocal[ R9]
28  R8 = R8 * R10
29  R10 = I1
30  R10 = R10 * R3 * R8
31  R8 = - R10
32  R10 = R0 + R8
33  Return
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a bit more obfuscated, but usefully more verbose.