# Best approach for 'manual' common subexpression elimination

Tags: performance-tuning, meta-programming

I have working code, but am looking for ways to make it more elegant.

I have a fairly large expression with plenty of repetition and structure. A shortened toy example is

```
expr = (a/(a + b))^4.5  + (b/(a + b))^3.5 + 
  (a/(a + b))^1.5 + Cosh[a + b]  + 
  Log[a/(a + b)] + Log[b/(a + b)]
```

I have prepared a set of rules that simplifies the expression, for example like this:

```
rules = {
  a + b -> sum, 
  a/sum -> g,
  b/sum -> h}
```

In my actual code I use pattern matching, and also create unique symbols for all the matches, see below for an example.

```
 Derivative[l_List, i_][δ][xv, ρ] :> 
  Symbol[StringJoin["$δd", StringJoin[ToString /@ l], "x", ToString[i]]]
```

The simplified expression, and the actual set of replacements is provided by the following function:

```
replaceone[expr_, rule_] := Block[{newtemps, unique},
  unique = Union@Cases[expr, rule[[1]], Infinity];
  newtemps = Thread[(unique /. rule) -> unique];
  Sow[newtemps];
  expr /. rule
  ]
{newekspr, temps} = Reap[Fold[replaceone, expr, rules]]
temps = Association[temps]
```

I can then prepare a function for efficient evaluation of the expression, like this, with a nested Block.

```
exprfun[av_, bv_] :=
 Block[{a = av, b = bv},
  Block[Evaluate[Keys[temps]], KeyValueMap[Set, temps];
   newekspr]]
```

I can `Compile` this function, although I suspect that the result is that the entire expression is expanded and simplified again.

```
Compile[{a, b}, Evaluate[exprfun[a, b]]]
```

Is this the best way of doing this?

Can I write a higher order function that takes my original expression, and a rules set, simplifies it and provides a optimised, and possibly compiled function?

What is the benefit of a nested With, and [`LetL`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451), that I have seen elsewhere, compared with this approach?

Comment: And `LetL` is defined as?

Comment: Next time, when using a function obtained from another post on this site, please link to the original post.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, of course. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Have you tried ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression`` on your expression?  A few refs: [(25136)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25136), [(31614)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31614), [(32097)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32097), [(58985)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58985)

Comment: @MichaelE2 My first attempts on `Experimental`OptimizeExpression` failed, but I tried it again on a smaller problem, and now it works. Don't know why. Still, it seems a bit inelegant to let the expression explode in complexity, for then to leave to `OptimizeExpression` to clean up afterwards. My expression, with an original leafcount of around 150 000 is now calculated in 13 ns, compared to 28ms before compilation. Still, I would really like to use the manual rules as well, as these intermediary results are interesting by their own as well.

Comment: Perhaps a small point, but `rules` contains typos. `nvec/Total[nvec], {i, nc}] ` and `$[Delta]d `.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks. I fixed the first one, but cannot find the second.

Comment: I should have been more explicit.  `$[Delta]d` should have been `$\[Delta]d`.  Also, a comma was needed between the two rules involving `Derivative`.  I fixed both and also cleaned the format a bit.  Please verify that I did not introduce other issues.  By the way, `nc` needs a value.