# Multiplication counting to illustrate HornerForm

Tags: date-and-time

`HornerForm[]` converts a polynomial with integer exponents into an equivalent polynomial that requires fewer total multiplications.  (It also has the benefit of making certain evaluations more robust to numerical roundoff errors when subtracting two large numbers.). Other operations, in particular addition, are not counted so we can consider them "free."

Example:

```
HornerForm[x^3 + (x + 1)^4]
```

(* 1 + x (4 + x (6 + x (5 + x))) *)

As far as I understand it, the input form requires 5 multiplications:  two for x^3 = x * x * x plus three for (x+1)*(x+1)*(x+1)

The output requires just 3 multiplications.  (Recall that additions are "free.")

I'd like a function for counting these multiplications to illustrate the reduction in multiplications afforded by `HornerForm`.

The function should work for *ratios* of polynomials, as does `HolderForm`.

[Related problems and solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25760/counting-multiplications-complexity-function) come close, but don't quite solve this problem (as far as I can see).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

metric[expr_] := 
 Total[Cases[expr, Power[_, n_Integer] :> Abs[n] - 1, {0,∞}]] +
  Count[expr, _Times, {0,∞}]

poly = x^3 + (x + 1)^4;

metric /@ {poly, poly // HornerForm}

(* {5, 3} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but no.  You're not counting the "traditional" multiplications: 
 `metric[(x+1)(x+2)]` should give $1$, but gives instead $0$.

Comment: Changed the level specification from Infinity to {0, Infinity}. Try it now

Comment: THERE we go.... thanks.  ($+1$, $\checkmark$).